# Why does docker build fail in a newly-initialized git repo?

Tags: git, docker, docker-build

Why does `docker build` fail/warn when run in a newly-initialized git repo?

```
$ mkdir dockergit
$ cd dockergit
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/projects/foo/dockergit/.git/
$ cat << EOF > ./Dockerfile
> FROM alpine:3.7 as base
> EOF
$ docker build -t tmp:tmp .
[+] Building 0.2s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 61B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:a3b9ee7f5e9bf7ad39ad1e9893be65001bd6367c7d10e2a682985d03e46458a9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/tmp:tmp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
WARNING: buildx: failed to get git commit: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
$
```

```
$ git --version
git version 2.11.0
```

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 23.0.0, build e92dd87
```

---

Update: Addressing the comments that "HEAD doesn't exist yet": what I don't understand is why there's any interaction between `git` and `docker` at all. I.e. why is `docker build` trying to/triggering anything related to `git`?

Comment: Well, `HEAD` doesn't exist yet when the repo is empty. You can't have a reference to a revision if there are no revisions to reference.

Comment: `HEAD` is ambiguous because there is no commit yet. After initializing the repository, create at least one commit. If there is nothing to commit, you can make an empty one by `git commit --allow-empty -m foo`.

Comment: I see only a warning, not a failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular bug was fixed in pull request [1592](https://github.com/docker/buildx/pull/1592) though whether your `buildx` is up to date with that is questionable since it was only merged to `master` three weeks back (as at the time this question was asked).

And the first *release* containing that PR was [`0.10.3`](https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/tag/v0.10.3), released on Feb 16, 2023 (roughly ten days ago, again as at the time of this question).

Until it *is* up to date, I'd suggest you just ensure you always have a `HEAD` so this warning doesn't happen.

---

Addressing your update about *why* `docker` and `git` are interacting, it's to provide useful information to the build environment should you wish to use it. See [here](https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/master/build/git.go) for the `git.go` file, which shows the items extracted, such as labels, the commit point, whether state is dirty (changed files after commit point), and so on.

For example, we like to bake the commit point into the application and log it on startup, so we know *exactly* what software is running when a bug report rolls in.

Issue [1290](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/1290) was the one that brought this `git.go` file into existence, there's a far more detailed explanation there, including the text:

> Therefore, we'd like to propose that `buildx` starts to record the following pieces of provenance when being run with a context that has a `.git` directory:
>
> - Git commit SHA of current checked out `HEAD`.
> - Include flag to indicate state of local clone (dirty).
> - Dockerfile path.